# How to debounce a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set a timer for `onChange` but I don't understand why it doesn't work. I tried several methods, but none of them worked. What can I change to make it work?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { debounce } from "lodash";
const Search = ({getQuery}) => {
const [text, setText] = useState('')

 const onChange = (q) => {
    setText(q)
    getQuery(q)
}

const handleDebounce = () => {
    debounce(onChange, 3000);
};

return (
    <section className='search'>
        <form>
            <input 
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Search characters'
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => handleDebounce( onChange(e.target.value), 3000)}
            autoFocus
            />
        </form>
    </section>
)}

export default Search
```

Comment: `handleDebounce` does not accept any arguments, but you're passing it two (`undefined`, and 3000). In your attempt to pass the `onChange` function to `handleDebounce`, you're actually calling it, bypassing the debouncing.

Comment: Also notice that `debounce` **returns** the debounced function. So as-is the debounced function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

removce `handleDebounce` completely and call your own `onChange` at the input `onChange`

```
onChange={onChange}
```

then adjust your `onChange` implementation as:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  const query = e.target.value;
  setText(query);
  debounce(() => getQuery(query), 3000);
}
```

Comment: I changed it, but now the Search input doesn't work. I can't write anything anymore.

Comment: I've adjusted my response, now it should work correctly.